# Include wordpress taxonomy slug in URL?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, slug

I have create a custom taxonomy which is essentially a second category, which would be either "food" or "drink".

Is there a way that I can include this taxonomy slug in the URL?

For example, a post that's in the category "free" that had the custom taxonomy "food", I would like to display as domain.com/free/food/post-title

Any idea how this can be achieved?

What's more - is it possible to have an archive page of all of the posts in the category "free" with the taxonomy "food"? For example, just going to domain.com/free/food and then showing all posts here.

Many thanks.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments